# android error in function video.start() and video.setVideoPath(url)

Tags: android

I need show a video on mobile app:

```
import android.widget.*;

import java.net.URL;  

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Url url= Url.getPath("android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.myvideo);

    VideoView video= (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    video.setVideoPath(url);
    video.start();
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to try this**

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vdVw);
        //Set MediaController  to enable play, pause, forward, etc options.
        MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        //Location of Media File
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video1);
        //Starting VideView By Setting MediaController and URI
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**it work just using mediaController like this**

```
    package com.example.video;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.MediaController;
    import android.widget.VideoView;
    import java.net.URL;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.nameid);  //id of video in activity
            //Set MediaController  to enable play, pause, forward, etc options.
            MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
            //Location of Media File
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.name);  //name of video in directory raw
            //Starting VideView By Setting MediaController and URI
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();


        }

}
```